# How to set a require conditions for nested mapping on struct array

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct, require

I have a nested mapping that has a group id and the item id so that it can cancel the order based on these id's specifically. But how do I set a condition e.g revert the error if the id doesnt exist or if the order is not from msg.sender.

```
// ticker is the group id and id is the item id
mapping(bytes32 => mapping(uint => Order[]) public orderBook;
mapping(bytes32 => mapping(uint => bool) public cancelOrder;

function cancelOrder(bytes32 ticker, uint id) external {
  Order[] storage orders = orderBook[ticker][id];

  // set a condition here

  // cancel the order
  cancelOrder[ticker][id] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My apologies but I think the code is not enough to give a full answer but I get your idea so I will go on based on assumptions

My share of knowledge: ***Mappings default value is 0*** so you can safely verify if the order exists if you can access any stored value in the mapping or check the Orders[].length if there is any order at all:

```
function cancelOrder(bytes32 ticker, uint id) external {
  // My apologies but I don't think you need this line
  // Order[] storage orders = orderBook[ticker][id];


  // There is an array stored here -> orderBook[ticker][id] so
  // if the ticker or the id doesn't exist, the mapping will be at its 
  // default value 0, therefore Orders[].length will be 0

  require(orderBook[ticker][id].length > 0, "Invalid ticker or Id");

  //you could refactor this require and verify with any stored value 
  //inside Orders[]

  //if the last require is not met the tx will be reverted, the message 
  //error "Invalid tick...." will be thrown and it will not 
  //reach this point

 cancelOrder[ticker][id] = true;

}
```

as of if the `msg.sender` is the owner of the order, assuming that the owner address is stored within the Order struct you could compare it like this:

```
require(msg.sender == Order[indexInTheArray].orderOwner, "Not owner");
```

I formulate my response based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448336/check-that-object-is-null-in-solidity-mapping)